# undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this2.tabValue()') error in react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-tablayout

I am trying to implement tab layout in react native. The layout is rendered. But in one of the tab when I click on an item it is not able to find the function.
I have followed the proper syntax, but not able to find the problem. Please help

I am trying to implement tab layout in react native. The layout is rendered. But in one of the tab when I click on an item it is not able to find the function.
I have followed the proper syntax, but not able to find the problem. Please help
My Class code

```
class TabViewExample extends Component {

  state = {
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      {
        key: '1',
        title: 'Chats'
      }, {
        key: '2',
        title: 'Contacts'
      }, {
        key: '3',
        title: 'Status'
      }
    ],
    navigate: this.props.navigation
  };

  _handleIndexChange = index => this.setState({index});

  _renderHeader = props => <TabBar {...props}/>;

  _renderScene = SceneMap({'1': this.renderFirst, '2': this.renderSecond, '3': this.renderThird});

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
    header: null
  };
  renderFirst()
  {
    return (
      <View
        style={[
        styles.container, {
          backgroundColor: '#EF9ADD'
        }
      ]}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>
            Welcome to React Native!
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>

    );
  }

  renderSecond()
  {
    return (
      <View
        style={[
        styles.container, {
          backgroundColor: '#0BEFF6'
        }
      ]}>
        <View style={styles.contacts}>
          <SectionList
            sections={[
            {
              title: 'N',
              data: ['Nitesh']
            }, {
              title: 'P',
              data: ['Paras']
            }, {
              title: 'S',
              data: ['Simran', 'Shikha', 'Sunil']
            }
          ]}
            renderItem={({item}) => <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} onPress={() => this.tabValue(item)}> // undefinded function error is here
            <Text style={styles.item}>{item}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>}
            renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <Text style={styles.sectionHeader}>{section.title}</Text>}/>
        </View>
      </View>

    );
  }

  renderThird()
  {
    return (
      <View
        style={[
        styles.container, {
          backgroundColor: '#E3A8FC'
        }
      ]}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>
            Welcome to React Native!
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>

    );
  }

  render() {
    return (<TabViewAnimated
      style={styles.container}
      navigationState={this.state}
      renderScene={this._renderScene}
      renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
      onIndexChange={this._handleIndexChange}/>);
  }

  tabValue = (value) =>{
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

    console.log('Paras');
    switch (value) {

      case 'Paras':
        console.log("paras Clicked!");
        navigate('ParasPage')
        break;

      case 'Nitesh':
        console.log("Nitesh");
        //this.props.navigation.navigate('NiteshPage')
        navigate('NiteshPage');
        break;

      case 'Simran':
        console.log("Nitesh");
        navigate('NiteshPage');
        break;

      case 'Shikha':
        console.log("Nitesh");
        //this.props.navigation.navigate('NiteshPage')
        break;

      case 'Sunil':
        console.log("Nitesh");
        //this.props.navigation.navigate('NiteshPage')
        break;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have binding issue. Either convert `renderBlah` methods into properties `renderFirst = () => {...}` or bind them to instance when creating a `SceneMap`

```
_renderScene = SceneMap({'1': this.renderFirst.bind(this)...)
```